Reactjs and AOS after page is loaded
I am using Animate on Scroll(AOS) plugin in reactjs. AOS Plugin intimates before the png image is loaded.
I see a greyed image instead of the actual image.
Here is the working url
I cannot share the full code. it is bit lengthy
// In App.tsx
useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1000,
      once: true,
    });
});



Hello, which greyed image? Can you share it?

I captured and showing it above

The image is appearing on my side. Why are you opening the website in Incognito?

I was able to replicate the greyyed image on my side. Here's what I've done:

The Devtools is opened when you load the website
In the Network tab in the Devtools, the option Disable cache is selected (check next image)


If this is the scenario that you're facing, unselect this option and the image will directly appear, without any grey intermediate image.
